# Allowing python use modules from other python installation

Tags: python, build, python-module, python-install

I normally use python 2.7.3 traditionally installed in `/usr/local/bin`, but I needed to rebuild python 2.6.6 (which I did without using `virtualenv`) in another directory `~/usr/local/` and rebuild numpy, scipy, all libraries I needed different versions from what I had for python 2.7.3 there...

But all the other packages that I want exactly as they were (meaning same version) in my default installation, I don't know how to just use them in the python 2.6.6 without having to download tarballs, build and installing them using `--prefix=/home/myself/usr/local/bin`.

Is there a fast or simpler way of "re-using" those packages in my "local" python 2.6.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall them. It may seem like a no-brainer to reuse modules (in a lot of cases, you can), but in the case of modules that have compiled code - for long term systems administration this can be an utter nightmare.

Consider supporting multiple versions of Python for multiple versions / architectures of Linux. Some modules will reference libraries in /usr/local/lib, but those libraries can be the wrong arch or wrong version.

You're better off making a requirements.txt file and using pip to install them from source.